# Soql inner join (Apex)

Tags: apex, soql

Morning guys, I am having a issue, I need to make a inner join in soql... 
Example:

- Process instance( table1)
- Process instance step(table 2)

I need to create a table mixing both tables, Id tabel 1 is process instance id in the 2, Table 1 primary key is a forien Key in table 2...

But soql will not support joins for tables
I have to write a complete code for this... do you know any other way apart form Apex class?

Comment: When you mean forieign key do you mean lookups?

Comment: Yes @pranay Jaiswal

Answer (score 1):

So Lets Assume this is your Process Table 1

```
Id(Primary Key),Name,Description__c,Other_Fields__c
```

And Process Table 2 Schema Looks like this

```
Id(Primary Key),Name,Process_Table1__c(Lookup / foreign Key to Table 1), Other_Fields__c
```

Here you can use Join, to get Parent_table1__c Fields querrying the Process_Table2__c, Its called as child-to-parent traversal

```
SELECT Id,Name,Process_Table1__r.Name,Process_Table1__r.Description FROM Process_Table2__c
```

Also, Another kind of join is Parent To child, Inner Querry, which allows yoqueryuerry child for a particular parrent

```
SELECT Id,Name,Description__c,(SELECT Id,Name FROM Process_Table2__r) FROM Parent_table1__c
```

Src: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_understanding.htm

Comment: I tried: 1. SELECT ProcessInstance.*,  (SELECT * FROM ProcessInstanceStep) From ProcessInstance;        But It will give parsing error

Comment: Select * doesn't work in apex, you To specify field names

Comment: I put in prosessInstanceId,  It says relational objest don't support

Comment: @MonicaHenao Check out the relationship name. it is possible that you specified the name incorrectly. The relationship name is NOT always __r, and pretty much NEVER __c

Answer (score 1):

[I would read up on relationships in SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_using.htm) because the concept of a `JOIN` as it works in a regular SQL database doesn't really conform to how SOQL works.

If you want ProcessInstances and their related Steps, you can run a query like this:

```sql
SELECT Id
,CompletedDate
,ElapsedTimeInDays
,ProcessDefinition.Name
,Status
,TargetObject.Type
,TargetObjectId
,(
    SELECT Id
        ,ActorId
        ,Actor.Name
        ,Comments
        ,CreatedById
        ,CreatedDate
        ,ElapsedTimeInDays
        ,IsDeleted
        ,IsPending
        ,OriginalActorId
        ,OriginalActor.Name
        ,ProcessInstanceId
        ,ProcessInstance.Status
        ,ProcessNodeId
        ,ProcessNode.Name 
        ,RemindersSent
        ,StepStatus
        ,TargetObjectId
    FROM StepsAndWorkitems
    ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC, Id DESC
)
FROM ProcessInstance
LIMIT 50
```

That will retrieve a Process Instance with all of it's "children".